# how to pass a list from controller to jsp and iterate it in javascript in spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a list

```
  List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

that contains many ids. I have to check in jsp if the id that user select is present in the list, error message is displayed on the page.

I have added a hidden in jsp

```
        <form:hidden path="idList" id="idList"/>
```

and in javascript i am fetching that by

```
    var idArray = new Array();
    idArray = $("#idList").val();
```

The idArray has all the ids with comma and space. Now this is not right. I know I am not doing it in right manner. Can anyone help?
My id which i need to find in the list is in $("#idUser").val()) which I get in javascript.

Please help.

Comment: can you give us the contents of `idArray` ?

Comment: List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for(BeanClass user: userList){                                   ids.add(user.getUserId());
}                 modelAndView.addObject("userIds", ids );    Got it?

Comment: `#branchIdList` does not exist in your example.

Comment: updated the code. it was a typo. branchIdList should be idList

Comment: sorry I meant, if you log the contents of `idArray` in your JS what is it?

Comment: @romhail why not make a ajax request to controller when user selects id and show validation error if it is.

Comment: @roly if the list contains 3 ids.... 4, 11 and 15 and if I log the content of idArray, it copmes [4 , 11, 15 ] which make it 11 individual elements rather than 3 elements. it consider even[  ,  and space ] as individual elements.

Comment: @Rembo i know I can user ajax to do so, but I want to submit the form from html and not the ajax. So If i use ajax, if the validation passes, I would want the html to continue submitting the from like it is happening now. Is it possible, if so can u show me how?

Comment: @romhail what type validation you want to perform only id? can your html form?

Comment: I want to check if the id selected in page by the user is present in the list of ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, what you want to do, then

suppose your jsp form is like:

```
<c:url value="/formaction" var="postUrl"/>
    <form:form id="myForm" method="post" action="${postUrl}" modelAttribute="formBean"> 
        <form:hidden path="ids"/>

        <label>Name:</label>
        <form:input path="name"/><br/>

        <label>Select Id:</label>
        <form:input path="id"/>
        <%-- <form:select path="id">
            <form:option value="0">--select id--</form:option>
            <form:options items="${formBean.ids}"/>
        </form:select> --%>

        <label id="idErr" style="color: red; display: none;">Please select another, id exists</label>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form:form>
```

and form model like:

```
public class FormBean {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Integer> ids;

    //getters and setters
}
```

in controller form bean added to model like this way:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model){

    FormBean formBean = new FormBean();
    formBean.setIds(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5)));
    model.addAttribute("formBean", formBean);               
    return "form";
}
```

then you can validate the `ids` in jquery like:

```
$("form#myForm").on('submit', function() {
   var ids = $('#ids').val(); //get values of <form:hidden path="ids"/> ,values will look like: 1,2,3,4,5
   var idsArray = ids.split(","); //split by comma
   var result = jQuery.inArray($('#id').val(), idsArray);//check user entered id exists in ids array
    if(result==-1){ 
        $('#idErr').hide();
        return true; //id not exists, submit form
    }
    else {
        //id exists, show error message
        $('#idErr').show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

But, better you should use `<form:select`..